# Delete directory on clean

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a C#/TypeScript project which uses webpack to bundle the TypeScript code into a directory `bundles`.

The directory `bundles` is created by webpack, which is triggered as a post-build event on the project.

I would like the `bundles` directory (or all of its children) to be deleted when I clean the project or solution. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

User [CleanPlugin](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin) for webpack. Here is my config for my server side code in node (see the plugins section uses `clean-webpack-plugin`):

```
plugins: [
    new CleanPlugin([ buildPath ], { root: projectRootPath }),
    // rest of plugins
],
```

The whole config

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

var projectRootPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');
var buildPath = path.join(projectRootPath, './build');


module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  cache: false,
  context: projectRootPath,
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: [ "./server/server.prod.js" ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "../build"),
    filename: "server.prod.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanPlugin([ buildPath ], { root: projectRootPath }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, enforce: "pre", loader: 'eslint-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: "post",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [ { loader: 'babel-loader' } ]
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: nodeModules, // nodeModules is an array variable
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./server'),
      path.resolve('./client'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ],
    extensions: [ ".json", ".js" ]
  }
};
```

Comment: How do I tie this in with the "Clean solution" option in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm not into .net , sorry.

Comment: @JamesMonger Look in the webppack config I posted, cleaning up is a part of the build process. Every time build process gets called, `CleanPlugin` gets called as one of the steps.